# Why does a constructor get preference over user defined operator?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand static_cast. I have two classes *From* and *To*. I'm trying to cast *From* to *To*. I have a constructor for *To* that takes *From*. I also have a user defined conversion operator to convert a *From* object to *To*. Why does the constructor get preference over the assignment operator?

```
class From;
class To
{
public:
    int y;
    To() { cout << "In To default constructor" << endl; }
    To(const To& sl2) { cout << "In To copy constructor" << endl; }
    void operator=(const To& sl2) { cout << "In To assignment operator" << endl; }
    ~To() { cout << "In To destructor" << endl; }
    To(const From& sl1) { cout << "In From-To constructor" << endl;}
};

class From
{
public:
    int x;
    From() { cout << "In From default constructor" << endl; }
    From(const From& sl2) { cout << "In From copy constructor" << endl; }
    void operator=(const From& sl2) { cout << "In From assignment operator" << endl; }
    ~From() { cout << "In From destructor" << endl; }
    operator To() const { cout << "Converting From to To" << endl; return To(); } 
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    From from;
    To to;
    to = static_cast<To>(from);
}
```

Comment: "I have a copy constructor for To that takes From." This isn't a copy constructor. This is just a constructor.

Comment: @Simple: Corrected! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is "because the standard says so" a valid answer for you?

`static_cast<T>(e)` has the same effect as `T t(e);` with `t` being the result of the cast. This follows the rules for *direct-initialization*, which considers applicable constructors through overload resolution before it considers user-defined conversion sequences.

I can provide the relevant standards quotes if that would put your mind at ease.